# How to read and parse binary file as Big Endian

Tags: python

I have a binary file which contains multiple types of structures.
The file contains the data as BIG Endian.

I'm trying to read the file and print the total number of records in the file.
(There are multiple types of structures and each one have different size)

here example of my code:

```
import os
from ctypes import *

class Header(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("time", c_ushort),
                ("typeA", c_ubyte, 4),
                ("typeB", c_ubyte, 4),
                ("size", c_ushort)]


headerSize = sizeof(Header)

file = open("D:\binaryFile.bin", "rb") 
numOfRecords = 0

while 1:
    # read the header
   sizeToRead =  headerSize
   data = file.read(sizeToRead)

   # if we get to the end of the file
   if not data: break

   numOfRecords = numOfRecords + 1

   # cast the data into Header structre
   headerInstance = cast(data, POINTER(Header)).contents

   # print the msg size (msg size = header size + payload size)
   print ("size = ", headerInstance.size)

   # read the rest of the body (payload size)
   sizeToRead = headerInstance.size - headerSize
   data = file.read(sizeToRead)

print ("Finished with: ", numOfRecords, " Records")
```

The problem is that using `read` or `cast` functions, do it in Little endian and not in Big Endian.

How can I read or cast to Big Endian ?

Comment: For starters, `"D:\binaryFile.bin"` is not what you think it is, because `'\b'` is a _backspace_ character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes.Structure` is for native byte order.

Derive from `ctypes.BigEndianStructure` instead of `ctypes.Structure`, but heed the warning in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.BigEndianStructure):

> Structures with non-native byte order cannot contain pointer type fields, or any other data types containing pointer type fields.